# iOS Enterprise Distribution (Ad Hoc) Provisioning Profile

Tags: xcode5, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

If I create a Distribution Provisioning Profile, why can I associate just one certificate with that? If I create a Development Provisioning Profile, I can associate multiple/all certificates in the iOS Dev Center.

The latter is handy because it means I can make use of existing Provisioning Profiles by just adding a new certificate to that profile. However, if I need to distribute my app on an Ad Hoc basis, I have to create a new Distribution Certificate in KeyChain, and then a new Distribution Provisioning Profile.

Is there an explanation behind this? I hope what I said makes sense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Development provisioning profiles have multiple certificates to allow multiple developers within your organisation to build and collaborate on the same app.

Distribution profiles only have one certificate because distribution builds are from your organisation, of which there is only one.

You only need to create the Distribution Certificate once per year. You can and probably should use the same distribution certificate to generate Ad Hoc provisioning profiles for multiple apps and also for AppStore provisioning profiles.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for the late reply. If a Distribution certificate was created on one machine, how do I obtain the certificates from that machine in order to use the provisioning profile (otherwise Xcode will complain that no valid signing certificates were found for the Distribution provisioning profile).

Comment: You can export the certificate PLUS private key from KeyChain.app, then install them onto the second machine.

Comment: @RhythmicFistman For Adhoc distribution can we create multiple provisioning profiles( i mean not updating the existing provisioning profile ) Creating with new name?

Comment: Yes, you can create new Ad Hoc provisioning profiles.